# Keyboard shortcut to preview method code in a popup

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, methods

What is the keyboard shortcut to preview a method's code as a pop-up?

I'm looking to preview the code inside of a given method much like one would preview the javadoc by placing the caret on the method and pressing F1.

I used to know this shortcut, but my memory is failing me harder than the various search algorithms and mom isn't home right now. ;-)

Comment: what is the keymap you are using? have you tried jos76's solution relative to your keymap, if it's different? :))

Comment: The keymap I'm using is Mac OS 10.5+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the shortcut keys to ***Quick Definition***. So jos76's idea is correct. But we have to map it to your keymap.

As I found  from ***Settings -> Keymap***, these are the keyboard shortcuts for ***Mac OS 10.5+***. You may change as your convenience.

[image]

And you can also try

- Place ***cursor on the method***.
- From Main menu ***View -> Quick Definition***(2nd row under view, You can also see shortcut key combinations appearing there). So there would be a pop up appearing with method implementation view as you suggested :))

So it looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Is `Ctrl+Shift+I` what you're looking for? Found it [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/viewing-definition.html)

Comment: ...it seems it would not be.